# Were there any voting districts with no votes for Obama?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, voting-records

Various news accounts and chain emails note that 50+ voting districts in Philadelphia, which are almost entirely black and with registered Republicans in the single digits, recorded zero votes for McCain in 2008 and/or Romney in 2012.

Are there any equivalent voting districts, perhaps in rural areas of red states, that recorded zero votes for Obama?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the purpose of this question, I'm going to assume that by "voting districts", you mean "precincts". You're correct that Romney received zero votes in a number of precincts - primarily urban precincts with majority African-American or Latino electorates. [PolitiFact.](http://www.politifact.com/ohio/statements/2012/nov/21/chain-email/emails-blog-posts-claim-mitt-romney-got-zero-votes/)

As you noted, Romney did better in rural areas, and got some *"shut-outs"* of his own in a few precincts throughout the country. One of these precincts is "Warren - Rennard's Garage 1-2" in Niobrara County, Wyoming. Gov. Romney received 60 votes, Pres. Obama (and all of the various 3rd party candidates) received 0 votes. [Niobrara County Elections.](http://soswy.state.wy.us/Elections/Docs/2012/Results/General/2012_Niobrara_County_General_PbP.pdf)

Comment: Please could someone, more informed of US politics than I am, explain to me the significance of this fact?

Comment: @WS2 Some people used it to allege voter fraud after the election, but precincts are small enough that there can be zero votes for a candidate in extreme cases.

Comment: Considering that there are *tens of thousands* or voting precincts in the US a few isolated odd results are to be expected statistically.

Comment: @WS2  There is no real significance to this other than that it indicates that some precincts have voters who are highly skewed towards one party or another.  This is mostly just trivia.